# How to make a list of the maximums in a list of lists (python)

Tags: python, list, max

Out of all the little lists, I have to make one list with the maximum even number out of each of the lists. If the list has odd numbers then the maximum is 0. So far my code is:

```
a=[]
b=[]
c=''
d=''
e=''
for i in range (len(res)):
    for j in range (len(res)):
        d=res[i][j]
        if (d%2 == 0):
            d=d
            a.append(d)
        else:
            d= 0
            a.append(d)
    c = max(a)
    b.append(c)
print b
```

The list is `[[1,2,3],[6,5,4],[5,7,9]]` and I need to get `[2,6,0]` but instead I keep getting `[2,6,6]`

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [[1,2,3],[6,5,4],[5,7,9]]
[ max( filter(lambda y: y % 2 ==0,(i+[0]))) for i in a]
>>>[2, 6, 0]
```

I think the code is quite self explanatory:

- `max(seq)` return a biggest number in the sequence
- `filter(fn, seq)` , will apply each element in seq with function fn, and keep element with fn(element) is logical true.
- list + [0] will be return a new list with one more element "0",just in case all elements in the list is odd number .

Update: in case of neg even, (credit should be give to @twasbrillig )

```
[ 0 if all(map(lambda z: z%2,i)) == True else max( filter(lambda y: y % 2 ==0,i)) for i in a]
```

Comment: Cool, but it doesn't support negative numbers.

Comment: to @twasbrillig you bring up a fairly thoughtful point. and your code is fairly clear than me .in my way I would use shorthand clause to keep the code in one-line .

Comment: Unfortunately if the input is `[[1,2,3],[6,5,4],[5,7,9]]`, the latest solution gives `[2, 6, [0]]`

Comment: again, thanks for the testing , my mistake. now the answer has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

`max` takes an optional `key` function which can be used to keep odd numbers out of the running. See https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max

```
def fn(x):
    return x if x % 2 == 0 else float("-inf")

a = [[1,2,3],[6,5,4],[5,7,9]]
b = [ max(L, key=fn) for L in a ]
print([i if i % 2 == 0 else 0 for i in b])
```

gives `[2, 6, 0]`

Works with negative numbers too. (If you don't need to support negative numbers, you can replace `float("-inf")` with `-1`.)

Answer (score 1):

As `max` function accepts an iterable, you can just use:

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[6,5,4],[5,7,9]]
>>> [max([m for m in i if m % 2 == 0] or [0]) for i in a]
[2, 6, 0]
```

Where `[m for m in i if m % 2 == 0]` gets the list of even numbers, and `max([m for m in i if m % 2 == 0] or [0])` gets the max even number (negative included) or 0 if no even number exists.

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[6,5,4],[5,7,9,-2]]
>>> [max([m for m in i if m % 2 == 0] or [0]) for i in a]
[2, 6, -2]
```

Comment: For your first example (without `-2`) I got `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`

Comment: @twasbrillig Yep you are right. I forgot max cannot accept empty lists. I'll try to fix it or I'll remove the answer.

Comment: In Python 3 you could use `default`: `[max((m for m in i if m % 2 == 0), default=0) for i in a]`. Note that the generator object will need the parentheses in this case.

Comment: @twasbrillig Nice. I'm not very Python 3 aware :). I tried your suggestion and it worked even with negative numbers.

Comment: This is my pick for best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Several points.

One, replace range with xrange. It doesn't create the full list.

Second, it appears that you are iterating over a 'matrix'. I had assumed that all the little lists were of indeterminate size. Nevertheless you are performing n*n evaluations. You could instead perform n+n by first finding the max then checking for evenness or oddness.

```
maxes = [ max( row ) for row in res ]
res_final = [ m if m % 2 == 0 else 0 for m in maxes ]
```

You'll have to double check the last line. But that should do.

Comment: My bad. You want the max even number. I missed that. I'll try and give another solution in a bit.